# проблема с загрузкой файлов на сервер. Flask выдает Bad Request

Tags: python, веб-программирование, файлы, flask, request

Пишу небольшое приложение на Flask.
При попытке загрузить файл на сервер выскакивает ошибка 400 Bad Request.
Ниже код программы:

```
@app.route('/add_t')
def add_theme():
    now_theme = Themes.query.order_by(Themes.date).all()
    return render_template("add_themes_teachers.html",   now_theme=now_theme)


@app.route('/add_t_file', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_t_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.files['file']
        return 'file uploaded successfully'введите сюда код
```

Вот так выглядит HTML шаблон:

```
{% block body %}

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead class="table-dark">
        <tr>
            <td>Тема</td>
            <td>Предмет</td>
            <td>Класс</td>
            <td>ФИО учителя</td>
            <td>Дата</td>
            <td>Добавить файл</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for el in now_theme %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ el.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ el.subj }}</td>
                <td>{{ el.form }}</td>
                <td>{{ el.teacher }}</td>
                <td>{{ el.date.strftime('%d.%m.%Y') }}</td>
                {% if el.file_way == 'None' %}
                <td>
                    <form action="/add_t_file" method="post">
                        <input type="file" name="file" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Отправить" class="form-control">
                    </form>
                </td>
                {% else %}
                    <td>
                    <h2>FILE SUCKS</h2>
                    </td>
                {% endif %}
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
{% endblock %}
```

Уже несколько часов бьюсь с проблемой, но никак не могу её решить. Можете подсказать, в чем тут ошибка?

Comment: Приведите код в виде текста, а не картинки

Comment: @CrazyElf переписал